# preg_match_all return proper offset with utf-8 in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8, preg-match-all

I'm currently trying to find the position of a certain series of characters in a mixed string (with japanese utf-8 characters and english characters). I currently pull the matches and the offsets like so:

```
preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $allmatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

But the offset seems to be far too large when there are Japanese characters in front of my matched string.

1. `こんいちはabcd` MATCH `こんばんは`
2. `abcdeabcd` MATCH `abcde`

The offset for both of those strings should be 10, but preg_match_all is returning a much higher number than that for the string with Japanese characters.

How can I make sure the offsets are standard for all strings?

**Edit: for those interested, my regex is quite basic. Just set to match a series of spaces:** `/( +){3}/iu`

Comment: Could you show us your regex?

Comment: You don't really need the regex, I've just done it with the string provided and matching 'MATCH' and it returns different offset values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself, used a roundabout method, but it works, the key is this regex:

`/[一-龠]|[ぁ-ゔ]|[ァ-ヴー]|[a-zA-Z0-9]|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９][々〆〤]/u`

I used that to preg_replace any character with a single digit number and then found offsets in the new string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the /u modifyer to the $regex to match unicode chars.

```
$regex = "/MATCH/u";
```

See: [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Thanks! But this was one of the first things I tried. I'm still getting a really large offset on my Japanese strings.